# Why does cout and return give different values in the following c++ code?

Tags: c++, increment, cout, ternary, post-increment

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fn1 (){
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    cout << (++a > b--)? (a+b):(a-b) ;
    a = 5;
    b = 6;
    return (++a > b--)? (a+b):(a-b);
}

int main (){
    cout << fn1();
}
```

> // Output: 01

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence.

```
cout << (++a > b--)? (a+b):(a-b);
```

is parsed as:

```
(cout << (++a > b--))? (a+b):(a-b);
```

which first evaluates the `cout <<` then the rest.